# AngularJs Update $interval delay time when this started

Tags: angularjs

my html code is :

```
<select ng-model='refresh_rate' ng-change="onRefreshRateChange()">
    <option value='10000'>10</option>
    <option value='30000' selected>30</option>  
    <option value='60000'>60</option>
    <option value='180000'>180</option>
    <option value='300000'>300</option>
</select>
```

and in my angular controller is :

```
var intervaL = $interval(function(){
    //[here]
    //after run every times i want update delay to $scope.refresh_rate
}, $scope.refresh_rate);
```

see this line in top code : 
//here i want update delay time to $scope.refresh_rate

now i want a code that put it Instead of this line

Comment: There is too much code there that has nothing to do with the question. When posting questions, try to reduce the code to a minimal that still reproduces and highlights your issue. This will help others help you.

Comment: @new-dev sorry for my bad ask... i want in angularjs $interval function after every times run update delay of $interval to $scope.refresh_rate

Comment: You can always (and should) edit your question to clean it. That's the whole point of these comments

Comment: @NewDev done...i edited my question.. how i can do it ?

Comment: Easiest would be to create a $timeout loop, then you can set the new $timeout to $scope.refresh every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the `$interval` rate you need to stop one `$interval` and start another.

Without going into particulars of whether the last `$interval` call should fire or cancel immediately - I'll let you handle that on your own - you can do the following:

```
var p = $interval(doSomething, $scope.refresh_rate);

$scope.$watch("refresh", function(){
  $interval.cancel(p);
  p = $interval(doSomething, $scope.refresh_rate);
});

function doSomething(){
  //...
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hb47IY9phgYeY3rtXtOL?p=preview)

**EDIT**:

You can also certainly do this in `onRefreshRateChange` instead of `$scope.$watch`. The difference is whether you care to change `$scope.refresh_rate` outside of your `<select>` - this is where you would use `$watch` vs. only in response to a change in `<select>`

Comment: doSomething function most be in controller function?

Comment: It needs to be accessible to the controller function, but yes - it's better if placed in the controller function.

Comment: The issue with this is that it will cancel the interval function before firing it off, so you may be missing calls here and there.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, yes, that's why I said "Without going into particulars" and "I'll let you handle that on your own", since this was not specified as a requirement in the original question.

Comment: what?! :) This is a Q&A site - ask whatever you need here, and either I or others would help you

Comment: @NewDev not work :( $scope.onRefreshRateChange = function(){
  $interval.cancel(p);
  p = $interval(getAllData(), $scope.refresh_rate);
 }
 
 function getAllData(){---}

Comment: @user2730309, pass the `getAllData` function - don't invoke it with `getAllData()`. Here's an example where it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/T0iTky31cpPno6vPilF9?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev worked ... i find my answer from your code :X :X :X... :X tnx :X if you can give me your email please :X

Answer (score 2):

Use a $timeout loop.

```
function loop(fn) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if (!$scope.stopBefore) {
            fn();
            $scope.stopAfter || loop(fn);
        }
    , $scope.refresh);
}
loop(doSomething);
```

Comment: That's a good approach - so long as there is no requirement to cancel immediately and start another timer.

Comment: Added some flags that could be used for control.

Comment: But not to be able to start the next timer right away. My bigger point is - the OP's requirements were not accurate

Comment: @ZackArgyle i most instead of $scope.refresh use $scope.refresh_rate ??

Comment: @ZackArgyle Work but if find my answer from New Dev Answer.. any way tank you :X